# targetSdkVersion 28 got red line error after uprade

Tags: android

I have clone my android project through .git lab my android project targetSdkVersion 28 will be highlighted with red color error together with dependency implementation and need required to change. Please refer the screenshot attached.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAqrx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6yWa.png)

The application previously working fine by using targetSdkVersion 28. After update gradle then Clean > Rebuild > Build (APK)s I tried to update installing the new release APK inside device without uninstalled the previous APK version then it appear App not installed. The packages appears to be corrupt.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoW9b.png)

How to solve this without changing the targetSdkVersion 28?
Please advise, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

set targetsdk version to 29, because your google play requires a minimum sdk version 29 after you update gradle,

Comment: I tried set target sdk to 29 others dependency will having error and it required Migration to Androidx. It is possible to fix without upgrading target sdk to 29?

Comment: no, because you already upgraded your gradle version , and your current gradle version requires sdkversion 29, you should upgrade your all dependencies according to sdk version 29, and its also good practice to use the latest targetversion because its works fine on the latest android version, the current latest version is 30, i will suggest you to set  target version 30 and upgrade your libraries accordingly